# apollo MockedProvider + Storybook not working

Tags: apollo, react-apollo, storybook

Using MockedProvider in Storybook doesn't seem to return anything.

When wrapping my component in the MockedProvider, it no longer throws an error that there's no Apollo client. So this proves that the MockProvider "works"

**Intended outcome:**

The following hook should return the data that's in the mock:

`const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(LATEST_SELL_SIGNALS)`

**Actual outcome:**

loading is `true` on first render and `false` on the second render

data is `undefined`

error is `undefined`

The fact that the loading props are working, should also suggest MockedProvider is running.

**Example story:**

```
import React from 'react'
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/react-testing'

import { LATEST_SELL_SIGNALS } from '~/common/queries'
import LatestSells from './LatestSells'

const mocks = [
  {
    request: {
      query: LATEST_SELL_SIGNALS,
    },
    result: {
      data: {
        yourData: { name: 'Storybook Data' },
      },
    },
  },
]


export default {
  title: 'Sales Components'
}

export const latest_sells = () => {
  return (
      <MockedProvider mocks={mocks}>
        <LatestSells />
      </MockedProvider>
  )
}
```

Where the LATEST_SELL_SIGNALS is this file:

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost'

export const LATEST_SELL_SIGNALS = gql`
  query {
    latestSellSignalsList(orderBy: createdAt_DESC, first: 10) {
      items {
        name
        ticker
        boughtAt
        soldAt
      }
    }
  }
`
```

the Component I'm wrapping is using react hooks like this:

`const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(LATEST_SELL_SIGNALS)`

The import for the query is the same in the Component as it is in the mock

please note this all works just fine with my normal Apollo Provider, I'm only having issues with the MockProvider not doing it's thing.

The component. also renders fine

**Version**
3.1.4

Answer (score 4):

In my project, I use `ApolloProvider` and `createMockClient` imported from `mock-apollo-client` to create mock client for my story book.
There are my components. Hopefully, it can help you. 
1. In `withApolloProvider.js`

```js
import React from 'react'
import { ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/react-hooks'
import { createMockClient } from 'mock-apollo-client'

export const withApolloProvider = ({ requestMockHandlers }) => {
 const mockClient = createMockClient()
 requestMockHandlers.mutations.forEach(mockHandler => {
  mockClient.setRequestHandler(mockHandler.type, mockHandler.handler)
 })
 requestMockHandlers.queries.forEach(mockHandler => {
  mockClient.setRequestHandler(mockHandler.type, mockHandler.handler)
 })
 return storyFn => {
  return <ApolloProvider client={mockClient}>{storyFn()}</ApolloProvider>
 }
}
```

2. In `NavBar.stories.js`

```js
import React from 'react'
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/core'
import muiTheme from '../../src/theme/muiTheme'
import NavBarDefault from './NavBarDefault'
import './navbar.scss'
import { addDecorator } from '@storybook/react'
import { RESET_CACHE } from '../../src/views/components/NavPanel/gql/mutation'

import gql from 'graphql-tag'
import { withApolloProvider } from '../withApolloProvider'

export default {
 title: 'Component Api|Navbar',
 includeStories: [],
}

const requestMockHandlers = {
 queries: [],
 mutations: [
  {
   type: RESET_CACHE,
   handler: () => {},
  },
 ],
}

addDecorator(
 withApolloProvider({
  requestMockHandlers,
 })
)

export const NavBarStory = () => {
 return (
  <ThemeProvider theme={muiTheme}>
   <NavBarDefault />
  </ThemeProvider>
 )
}
```

3. In `NavBar.stories.mdx`

````js
import { Meta, Story, Preview,Props } from '@storybook/addon-docs/blocks';
import NavBarDefault from './NavBarDefault'

import * as stories from './NavBar.stories.js';

<Meta title="Component Api|NavBar" />

# NavBar
With `MDX` we can define a story for `Nav Bar` right in the middle of our
markdown documentation.




  <Story name="Basic">
    {stories.NavBarStory()}
  </Story>


```jsx
<NavBarDefault />
```

# PropTypes

<Props of={NavBarDefault}/>
````

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The `mock-apollo-client` indeed does work. However it's not the official solution from the apollo team. I'm specifically looking for an answer on how to get the MockedProvider (the official one) working with storybook.

Upvoted for others, but not the answer to this specific question.

Comment: I looked into this as well and my opinion is that there isn't a well supported official solution. Looking through recommended tools might end up pointing you to `apollo-client` mock, but that solution breaks down when you are querying through `@apollo/react-hooks`. I think Michael's suggestion is the best out one there right now :D

Answer (score 1):

The shape of the mocked result MUST be exactly the **same** as the query, otherwise, the value of the `data` of the `useQuery` will be `undefined`.

Since the query is

```
const LATEST_SELL_SIGNALS = gql`
      query {
        latestSellSignalsList(orderBy: "desc", first: 10) {
          items {
            name
            ticker
            boughtAt
            soldAt
          }
        }
      }
    `;
```

thus the result of the mocked data must be

```
result: {
  data: {
    latestSellSignalsList: {
      items: [
        { 
          name: 'Storybook Data', 
          ticker: 'STB', 
          boughtAt: 'boughtAt', 
          soldAt: 'soldAt'
        }
      ],
    },
  },
},
```

Updated Story

```
import React from 'react';
import { gql, useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing';

export default {
  title: 'MockedProvider',
};
const LATEST_SELL_SIGNALS = gql`
  query {
    latestSellSignalsList(orderBy: "desc", first: 10) {
      items {
        name
        ticker
        boughtAt
        soldAt
      }
    }
  }
`;

const mocks = [
  {
    request: {
      query: LATEST_SELL_SIGNALS,
    },
    result: {
      data: {
        latestSellSignalsList: {
          items: [
            { name: 'Storybook Data', ticker: 'STB', boughtAt: 'boughtAt', soldAt: 'soldAt' },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
  },
];

const LatestSells = () => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(LATEST_SELL_SIGNALS);
  console.log('LatestSells', { loading, data });
  return <div>{JSON.stringify(data)}</div>;
};

export const Default = () => {
  return (
    <MockedProvider mocks={mocks}>
      <LatestSells />
    </MockedProvider>
  );
};
```

The console output:

[image: The console output]